# When use where condition with NHinernate Entity exception occured

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

This works

```
var a = Session.Query<CaptureHistory>()
```

But this is not working and throw ADOException.

```
var a = Session.Query<CaptureHistory>().Where(c => c.CaptureName == "");
```

Exception

"While preparing select capturehis0_.CaptureCode as CaptureC1_2_,  capturehis0_.CaptureName as CaptureT4_2_ from CaptureHistory capturehis0_ where capturehis0_.CaptureName=? an error occurred"}

InnerException

"OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size."

Hibernate mapping for field CaptureName

```
<property name="CaptureType" column="CaptureName" type="String"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, which database are you using and are you really required to use OleDb? If you have MSAccess, get the `NHibernate.JetDriver` package for example...

If you have to use ole db, maybe try to disable command preparation by setting `prepare_sql` to `false`

```
 <property name="prepare_sql">false</property>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works when prepare_sql set false. I already did this but i made changes in hibernate.cfg.xml but hibernate-configuration section is also exist in app.config. that's why it not works.